# Why is happening a list index out of range in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im learning Python and I encountered a `IndexError: list index out of range` in this part of the code: `last_element2 = each_list2[-1]`. I have tried to solve it by adding the each_list2 is not 0 but it still not works.

How can I solve it? Thanks!

```
for each_list2 in nodesAbandonedTotal:
   if each_list2 is not 0:
      last_element2 = each_list2[-1]
      final_element2 = last_element2[-1]
      if final_element2 == "get_started" or final_element2 == "saludo":
         countGetStarted = countGetStarted + 1
      elif final_element2 == "ae-1" or final_element2 == "ae-d":
         countFaltaEntendimiento = countFaltaEntendimiento + 1
```

Comment: Paste the complete stack trace of the exception

Comment: You should provide a definition for `nodesAbandonedTotal`, or minimally some sample data.

Comment: not sure if related but if you're trying to check the length of the list `if each_list2 is not 0:` should be `if len(each_list2) is not 0:`, or is it the case that `each_list2` can be a number or a list?

Comment: If  `nodesAbandonedTotal` has an empty list, then `each_list2[-1]`  will give `IndexError`

Comment: You should be using `!=` instead of `is not`.

Comment: `if each_list2:` should be fine

Comment: @h0r53 If you read my statement correctly , I have used the word "has". So it's a nested list

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. L.Grozinguer and jmunsch answers worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the answers provided by @Leo and @Roshin are close, they fail to verify that `last_element2` has elements before it is indexed. Since your original issue is related to indexing issues, solutions should not be prone to additional indexing issues.

For example, try the payload `nodesAbandonedTotal = [ [ [ ] ] ]` and you will see both proposed solutions fail.

Here is an amended solution that accounts for the case of `last_element2` being empty.

```
for each_list2 in nodesAbandonedTotal:
    if each_list2:
        last_element2 = each_list2[-1]
        if last_element2:
            final_element2 = last_element2[-1]
        else:
            final_element2 = None
        if final_element2 == "get_started" or final_element2 == "saludo":
            countGetStarted = countGetStarted + 1
        elif final_element2 == "ae-1" or final_element2 == "ae-d":
            countFaltaEntendimiento = countFaltaEntendimiento + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have serious indentation error in you code :

```
for each_list2 in nodesAbandonedTotal:
   if each_list2:
      last_element2 = each_list2[-1]
      final_element2 = last_element2[-1]
      if final_element2 == "get_started" or final_element2 == "saludo":
         countGetStarted = countGetStarted + 1
      elif final_element2 == "ae-1" or final_element2 == "ae-d":
         countFaltaEntendimiento = countFaltaEntendimiento + 1
```

This assumes that `each_list2` is a list, and if it is an integer, use : `each_list2 != 0`

Comment: Instead of `if each_list2 != []` use `if each_list2:`

Comment: This could still throw an error. Imagine `nodesAbandonedTotal = [ [ [ ] ] ]`. Then `each_list2 = [ [] ]`, and `final_element = []`, and you will still receive an index out of bounds error.

Comment: The same way you solved the other errors, check for existence of an element before indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the list has items

```
if len(each_list2) > 0:
```

or

```
if each_list2:
```

This will check that the list is not empty. 
In addition, the `if final_element2 == "get_started" or final_element2 == "saludo":` and `elif final_element2 == "ae-1" or final_element2 == "ae-d":` needs to be inside the `if each_list2:` check

```
for each_list2 in nodesAbandonedTotal:
   if each_list2:
        last_element2 = each_list2[-1]
        final_element2 = last_element2[-1]
        if final_element2 == "get_started" or final_element2 == "saludo":
          countGetStarted = countGetStarted + 1
        elif final_element2 == "ae-1" or final_element2 == "ae-d":
          countFaltaEntendimiento = countFaltaEntendimiento + 1
```

Comment: Although this is the right approach, based on the original code both `each_list2` and `final_element2` need to be checked for elements before they are indexed.

Comment: Tnx for that note, added to the solutin

Comment: Unfortunately your amended code does not resolve the issue. Try with `nodesAbandonedTotal = [ [ [ ] ] ]` and see for yourself.

Comment: `nodesAbandonedTotal` is not a list of list in list it's [[]]

Comment: How can we be so certain? We were never provided sample data for `nodesAbandonedTotal`. Regardless, a solution that includes potential for indexing errors, for a question that involves indexing errors, does not appear to be a complete solution.

Comment: So what will happen in case of [[[[]]]] then your solution will not work.

Comment: But it does, try for yourself